# Format string padding

Tags: visualforce

I am taking an object and putting some attributes in a picklist. I want to format the string so that is has some padding.

```
for ( Course_Detail__c c : courses ) {
            string temp = c.FKCourse__r.Name + ' - ' + c.StartDate__c;
            allCourseDt.add(new SelectOption(c.Id, temp));
```

I want to format the Course Name so they are aligned in the picklist.

[image]

I want the courses to line up and the date to line up. Is there a string format function that I can add padding?

Comment: Don't understand what your issue is. Your current temp string seems perfectly aligned unless they need to trim for themselves. Can you show us a screenshot / page of what your issue is?

Comment: Did you try using the leftPad(), rightPad(), and center() methods? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to achieve the result you desire here. As the included screenshot shows, Salesforce picklists do not use a monospaced font, which means that you can't simply insert spaces for characters even if Salesforce didn't strip them out. For example, the following two strings both consist of a 5 letter word, four spaces and another 5 letter word:

> "Wowed    Crowd"
>
> "Split    Bills"

As you can see, the same number of characters does not mean the same length strings, which is why inserting spaces is not going to be of any use to you. If you had a monospaced font it'd be fine:

```
"Wowed    Crowd"
"Split    Bills"
```

You could potentially use some kind of CSS hack to force the picklist to use a monospaced font, but that'd be entirely unsupported and likely to break in the *very* near future. In other words, **don't use a CSS hack**.

As ugly as it is, if you're using standard page layouts etc. for this you'll just have to lump it. If you're building a custom Visualforce page or similar, then you could potentially use a different kind of interface for the same job, maybe just having  a table of contacts with a column for a selection checkbox/radio button, one for name and one for date.

Answer (score 0):

As LaceySnr has already mentioned, it is impossible to style `<apex:selectOptions>`. There are css tricks to do that but that's not recommended.

But if you are really intended to achieve this. You can try the following steps which should work for you:

1. Give up on `<apex:selectOptions>`. Instead, use standard html select. Pop up the options and save the results using javascript remoting.
2. In options, use css style: white-space: pre to keep the white spaces.
3. It should be easy for you to fill the string with white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use one of the leftPad(), rightPad(), or center() methods to get the same number of characters in each string. From there you can choose to have them displayed in a monospace font by setting the style attribute on the apex:selectList. This is not a hack since the visualforce developer's guide specifically states that this attribute is used for adding inline CSS styles.

[image]

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:SelectList style="font-family: courier">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Wowed Crowd" itemlabel="Wowed Crowd" />
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Split Bills" itemlabel="Split Bills" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```